# Is there better way to do this query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE a.re_id = 3443499
AND a.id IN 
(
   SELECT b.rsp_id FROM b
   WHERE b.f_id = 9
   GROUP BY b.rsp_id
   HAVING FIND_IN_SET(16, GROUP_CONCAT(b.o_id)) > 0
   AND FIND_IN_SET(15, GROUP_CONCAT(b.o_id)) > 0

   UNION

   SELECT b.rsp_id FROM b
   WHERE b.f_id = 4
   GROUP BY b.rsp_id
   HAVING FIND_IN_SET(5, GROUP_CONCAT(b.o_id)) > 0
)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Here "f_id" is array and its values are those in first parameter of "FIND_IN_SET" function.
For example

```
9=>(
 16,
 15
),
4=>(
 5
)
```

Sample data for those 2 folumns in table b, 2 columns f_id and o_id

```
f_id o_id
9    15
9    18
9    23
4    5
3    8
```

Comment: I means its an user input input as array from form checkboxes.

Comment: Added more text to question now.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

The gist of this answer is that the current query does not run.  So, fix the syntax and ask *another* question.

First, you could write the query so it is syntactically correct.  The query will fail as written, because the first subquery returns at least two rows and the second only one.

Second, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, unless you specifically want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Third, the `ORDER BY` will generate an error.

Fourth, the `GROUP_CONCAT()` is dangerous and unnecessary.

I'm not 100% sure this is the intention, but I would start with a query like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.re_id
FROM a
WHERE a.re_id = 3443499 AND
      a.id IN (SELECT b.rsp_id
               FROM b
               WHERE b.f_id = 9
               GROUP BY b.rsp_id
               HAVING MAX(b.o_id = 16) > 0 AND
                      MAX(b.o_id = 15) > 0
              )
UNION ALL
SELECT b.rsp_id, NULL
FROM b
WHERE b.f_id = 4
GROUP BY b.rsp_id
HAVING MAX(b.o_id = 5) > 0
ORDER BY id;
```

Then, if you want this optimized, I would suggest asking *another* question, along with relevant information about the table structures and current performance.

Comment: O Yes, that order by was just id, not a.id "a." added while posting this question. But yet purpose of union/all was to get those rsp_id, and in your answer union is completely different?